# Domain user missing start menu icons on first login

Tags: windows, windows-10, login, domain, windows-domain

I work in a school and we are having an issue with Start menu icons not showing on first login. A simple log out and log back in fixes it but I would like to get it fixed once and for all.

We were running Windows 10 LTSB and never had this issue but after reinstalling and going to Windows 10 Education it has cropped up.

[When a domain user first logs on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBsWI.png)

[After the domain user has logged off and back on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3edo.png)

I wondered if this might be something to do with Group Policy but as it was working fine on LTSB (and still does as we have not moved all the machines over) it starts to make me think it is not?

I have noticed that restarting Explorer.exe will also fix the issue instead of relogging.

The build is - Windows 10 Education - 1803 - 17763.504

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems that as soon as the user is logged in for the first time, it is still syncing up the profile to the active directory.

Comment: Would seem weird that it works fine on LTSB though? I know LTSB has less to load but I doubt it would make much difference